# How to iterate the values through the input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-template

My code:

```
<div class="form-group row text-right" *ngFor='let row of vipInput'>
  <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-label m-t-5" for="password-h-f">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{row.value}}" id="email-h-t" type="email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeInputs('vip',i)">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="vipInputIncrement('val')">ADD</button>
```

My array: `vipInput = [{"value":"1","value":"2","value":"3"}]`

```
  vipInputIncrement(val) {
    this.vipInput.push({'val':''});
  }
```

Here I am not able to push the value to my array 'this.vipInput' only empty values are pushed.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: can you console.log(val) inside vipInputIncrement() function

Comment: Hi Dinesh my add button is out of the iterating tag,so how can i pass the value to vipInputIncrement()?

Comment: then  what about this code (click)="vipInputIncrement('val')   ? in your code?

Comment: Actually at this point I want the help,how to push the value entered into the array.

Comment: Show the component file for this template otherwise its not possible to determine why you are not able to push to the array bound to your template.

Comment: It seems unclear what should happen, I mean there is first of all nothing to iterate, there is just one object in the array, do you actually mean that it looks like this: `[{"value":"1"},{"value":"2"},{"value":"3"}]`? Secondly, what do you want to pass in the `vipInputIncrement`, which value? And third, why do you even want to pass any value to that function, since you'd not be using it anyway in your function.

Comment: AJT_82 is right. You're pushing multiple small objects in your array, but the initial value you showed in ONE big object. You need to decide which data structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your array and put it with this format

```
[{"value":"1"},{"value":"2"},{"value":"3"}]
```

and later try this

```
vipInputIncrement(val) {
    this.vipInput.push({'value':this.vipInput.length+1});
}
```

Note that "val" have been changed by "value"
Actually you should remove param this is not being used.

```
vipInputIncrement() {
    this.vipInput.push({'value':this.vipInput.length+1});
}
```

And in html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="vipInputIncrement()">ADD</button>
```